# Eclipse source code warnings

Tags: java, eclipse

Below you can see an image of the source code (in eclipse) where the warnings are occurring. I am new to this, and am therefore unaware of how to solve this.

Source code image
[image]

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: 1. [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/). 2. Don't post it as a picture; copy your code and put it in the question here. 3. You need to tell us what the warning messages are.

Comment: just hover the yellow light bulb, there will be an explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of warnings is related to usage of deprecated classes.

If you have the need to use that deprecated class (for a big reason) in that case you can add this:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
```

That will remove the warnings.

But, ... Here is big but...

You should to avoid usage of deprecated classes/methods because of every part which is marked as deprecated is marked as deprecated for a reason. For example, some code (method, class, etc) is marked as deprecated because it is planned to be removed, have better solution, works non-predictive or some other reason.

From other side, everything what is annotated as @Deprecated have to discourage all the programmers using it and try to implement his replacement or another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like Felix mentioned, hover over those "warnings/messages" and it will show you a hint.

In this case, you are calling a **deprecated** class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html